# How to unload multiple user forms

Tags: vba, userform

I'm not having any success in unloading multiple user forms. Here is the list of my user forms.

[image]

I googled this problem and came across the following code:

```
Sub testIt2()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = VBA.UserForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Unload VBA.UserForms(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code doesn't work unfortunately. It doesn't recognize any of my forms.

Here is an extract when I step through the code. It doesn't recognize any of the forms.

[image]

Comment: are the forms open at this time?

Comment: Yes they are. The worskbook is a tool used to calculate something. The user works through multiple userforms (which need to be kept open so they can go in and edit the info if needed). At the end there is a macro to save the details to an access dabase and it is at this point that I want the userforms unloaded. Otherwise the information is retained from a previous piece of work.

Comment: What does  `debug.? VBA.UserForms.Count` in the immediate window give?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I'm not sure what you mean so I added a picture to the original post above showing the screen when I step through the code. It seems none of my userforms are recognized. The macro doesn't crash, it just doesn't recognize the userforms if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, so check what the count actually gives you in the immediate pane. https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/  you can start to debug/fix.

Comment: The count is  0. It doesn't pick up any userforms in the count.

Comment: Did you try the count before you ran the code?

Comment: Yes and it says there is 1 userform (when looking at immediate window) but I have about 25 in the workbook. Does it just check for open or hidden ones?

Comment: They are only open when they are being used, like if you do `UserForm1.Show` or `Load UserForm1` - otherwise they are just there in waiting

Comment: Or... can you actually see that they are open? I mean, can you interact with them?

Comment: Some are just in waiting. The problem is then the user goes to do a new calculation and opens up once of the userforms, it contains values from a previous job. All I want to do is unload all of the userforms that are hidden. The reason they are hidden is that the user can click back into the userform and check there inputs before the work is saved.

Comment: Ok, What code is used to LOAD and HIDE the userforms?

Comment: userform.show and userform.hide. For example, one of the userforms is called CalculatePrem in which case I use CalculatePrem .hide/CalculatePrem.show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done this way:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim ufObject As Object

    For Each ufObject In VBA.UserForms
        Debug.Print "unloading..."; ufObject.name
        Unload ufObject
    Next ufObject

End Sub
```

Simply iterate through the collection `VBA.UserForms` and unload whathever you find there.